# Mysql on Ubuntu, not able to login [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'] I made lots of tries

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Until yesterday I was able to work on my Ubuntu computer, connecting to Mysql with a root user. Today every application I have is not able to connect to mysql. I didn't change its configuration or psw of my root user.

I made lots of tries. Here they are:

```
mysql -uroot -p
mysql -uroot -p --host=127.0.0.1
```

They all give me this:

```
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Then, I tried to launch the following commands (they are not in the exact order I gave them... as you will see, I stumbled upon some errors of 'Unable to lock ./ibdata1' and even 'The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!' ... killing pending processes and restarting solved these problems, but still I can't connect to mysql with root):

```
$ ps -aux | grep mysql
mysql     3249  0.0  1.2 550092 48580 ?        Ssl  14:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mattia    3616  0.0  0.0  15968   940 pts/11   S+   14:33   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql


$ mysql --no-defaults --force --user=root --host=127.0.0.1 --database=mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)


$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables
150331 14:32:31 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150331 14:32:31 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Mattia-PC-Linux.lower-test
150331 14:32:31 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Mattia-PC-Linux.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13)
150331 14:32:31 [ERROR] Aborting

150331 14:32:31 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete


sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo service mysql stop

sudo service mysql start
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start


$ tail -n1000 /var/log/mysql/error.log
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
150331 14:19:11 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150331 14:19:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150331 14:19:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150331 14:19:18  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150331 14:19:19 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 1515015658
150331 14:19:19 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150331 14:19:19 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150331 14:19:19 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150331 14:19:20 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150331 14:19:20 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
150331 14:21:44 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

150331 14:21:44 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150331 14:21:44  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150331 14:21:45  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1515015658
150331 14:21:45 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150331 14:21:48 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150331 14:21:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150331 14:21:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150331 14:21:48  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150331 14:21:49 InnoDB: 5.5.41 started; log sequence number 1515015658
150331 14:21:49 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
150331 14:21:49 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150331 14:21:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150331 14:21:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150331 14:21:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

This is **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Any idea?

Comment: run an update + upgrade and specifficly update mysql-server, had the same today

Comment: really? what commands should I run?

Comment: sudo apt-get update - sudo apt-get upgrade - sudo apt-get updgrade mysql-server

Comment: sudo apt-get update mysql-server is not a valid command. do you mean sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-server ? It's already the latest version. did you launched other commands to solve your problem?

Comment: ment upgrade yeah, no that was all.

Comment: Well. this is daunting :( what if I launch dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5 ? do I lose data?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the problem in this way:

```
kill mysql.pid process
sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

From now on I was able to enter the mysql console and I found that root user was not present!!!
I had to create it